# d3.js when click outside the elements, hide the element

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have some tootips in my page. There is one tooltip(div) contains a input box and a button. I want to click outside the tooltip and then hide the tooltip. I tried this:

```
d3.select("body")
.on("click",function(){
    d3.select("#tooltip")
    .classed("hidden",true);
});
```

This works, but when I click the input box want to input some value, the tooltip still hide. How can I hide the tooltip only when I click outside the tooltip?

I also tried:

```
d3.select("body").filter().on("click",function(){})
```

But I don't how it works, I cannot select all elements except the tooltip(div).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
var tooltip = d3.select("#tooltip");
var tooltipWithContent = d3.selectAll("#tooltip, #tooltip *");

function equalToEventTarget() {
    return this == d3.event.target;
}

d3.select("body").on("click",function(){
    var outside = tooltipWithContent.filter(equalToEventTarget).empty();
    if (outside) {
        tooltip.classed("hidden", true);
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LukaszWiktor/53yok58w/

Comment: We use `d3.selectAll("#tooltip *")` could select all child nodes and their child nodes. I wonder how to select all child nodes and their child nodes by javascript? not d3.js. Using `Node.childNodes()` can only select child nodes under the Node, but there doesn't include "child nodes' child nodes".

Comment: @Yawei pure JavaScript can also do it. Just use `document.querySelectorAll("#tooltip *")` - this method broadly supported http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector